# How to set html page to $webcontainer without horisontal scrolling

Tags: jasonette

I have developing the app on jasonette framework. I have use the $webcontainer such as default browser, but i have a problem with horisontal boundaries.

I have add injected script with meta tag:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0">');
```

But it is not work such as I want. I check this page on default chrome browser it shows normal.
[image: my app]
[image: chrome]

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the page in design mode in which you want to hide the horizontal scroll bar.
2. Click on Page > Page Properties.
3. Go to Metadata tab.
4. Paste following code in HTML for head section. Click OK.

You can use a CSS property called 'overflow' and set it to 'auto'. That will add both, vertical and horizontal scrollbars. If you want a vertical scrollbar, add 'overflow-y' to the body of your html.

After building a couple of these and battling through unexpected bugs in the QA process, I wanted to find out once and for all how to create a horizontal scroller with minimal code that worked as expected across all types of devices.